# Unknown extra item appearing in list (firebase)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

For some bizarre reason, when I render a list in Vue with data coming from Firebase, it adds an extra item to the bottom that isn't actually in the Firebase database.

Baffled!

[image]

```js
...

created () {
  this.$watch('projectId', (projectId) => {
    if (projectId) {
      this.$bindAsObject('deadlines', projectsRef.child(this.$route.params.id + '/deadlines'))
    }
  }, {
    immediate: true
  })
}

...
```

```html
...

<div v-for="deadline in deadlines" :key="deadline['.key']" class="table__row grid-x">
  <div class="cell small-5">{{ deadline.description }}</div>
  <div class="cell small-6 text-right"><a href=''>{{ deadline.date }}</a></div>
  <div class="cell small-1 text-right"><a class="icon icon__trash--black" @click="removeDeadline(deadline)"></a></div>
</div>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like reverting to vuefire's data binding solves the issue.

```js
firebase () {
  return {
    deadlines: projectsRef.child(this.$route.params.id + '/deadlines')
  }
}
```